# JsonConstructor fails on IEnumerable property?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

So setting an enumerable using an accessor works great.

```
public class SetEnumerableWithAccessor
{
    public IEnumerable<string>? Strings { get; set; }
}

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new SetEnumerableWithAccessor
{
    Strings = new [] { "test" }
});

JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SetEnumerableWithAccessor>(json);
```

Setting an enumerable using a constructor fails.

```
public class SetEnumerableWithConstructor
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public SetEnumerableWithConstructor(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        Strings = strings.ToImmutableList();
    }
    
    public ImmutableList<string> Strings { get; }
}

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new SetEnumerableWithConstructor(new string[] { "test" }));
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SetEnumerableWithConstructor>(json);
```

This is the exception that is thrown.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'CertusLogic.Audio.Test.FourierTransformTest+SetEnumerableWithConstructor' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConstructorParameterIncompleteBinding(Type parentType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectWithParameterizedConstructorConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

Really banging my head on something that feels like it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Changing it to a more concrete enumerable implementation doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It looks like the problem is `strings.ToImmutableList();`

Comment: Okay it does work if you take the ToImmutableList off. Is there a reasonable explanation or this a bug?

Comment: I feel like it should be a documented gotcha if it's intentional. I'm guessing that it's actually checking what the functionality within `SetEnumerableWithConstructor` is. If I change the constructor to accept an `ImmutableList<string>` and do away with the `.ToImmutableList();`, it works fine. It might be worth [submitting it as a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues), though I'm not sure if it will be considered as such. It seems to be a bug or a failing of the documentation though.

Answer (score 4):

When deserializing a class with a parameterized constructor, Sytem.Text.Json requires that constructor parameters match with serialized properties.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0#immutable-types-and-records) <sup>[1]</sup>:

> The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names **and types**. Matching is case-insensitive, and the constructor parameter must match the actual property name even if you use `[JsonPropertyName]` to rename a property.

Thus you must add a constructor to your class with an `ImmutableList<string> strings` argument and mark that constructor, and only that constructor, with [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute):

```
public class SetEnumerableWithConstructor
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public SetEnumerableWithConstructor(ImmutableList<string> strings) => Strings = strings;

    public SetEnumerableWithConstructor(IEnumerable<string> strings) => Strings = strings.ToImmutableList();

    public ImmutableList<string> Strings { get; }
}
```

And now your class will be serializable.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wo5TlF.

Note that there is currently an enhancement [[JsonSerializer] Relax restrictions on ctor param type to immutable property type matching where reasonable #44428](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44428)  open asking to loosen the argument type matching restrictions, with nothing scheduled as of April 2023.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>  The documentation was updated in 2023.  At the time this question was asked, the documentation [merely stated](https://web.archive.org/web/20221022215653/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

> The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names.