# Deserialization using System.Text.Json fails when constructor parameter doesn't have the same type as the matching property

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialization, system.text.json

What would be the best way of making STJ deserialize correctly for cases where the type of the constructor parameter does not match the type of the property with a matching name?

Consider the following code sample:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

string data = """
              {
                "Ints": [24, 43, 54, 23]
              }
              """;

var parsed = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(data)!;

class Data
{
    public Data(IEnumerable<int> ints)
    {
        Ints = ints.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Ints { get; }
}
```

The type of the constructor parameter `ints` does not match the type of the property `Ints`. This makes deserialization fail although this use case looks very reasonable.

Deserialization works as expected with Newtonsoft but I'd like to use STJ if possible.

The exception message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Data' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization.
Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object.
Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled.
The match can be case-insensitive.
```

Comment: The best would be using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: This is a documented restruction, and looks like a duplicate of [JsonConstructor fails on IEnumerable property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72268018/3744182), agree?

Comment: Indeed seems like it. I'd be grateful if some moderator could mark it as one. Thanks

Comment: @serge would you say it is a good idea to come to Stackoverflow and recommend Newtonsoft for a .Net project in 2023?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [How to use immutable types and non-public accessors with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability?pivots=dotnet-7-0) docs. One way to handle is to introduce `JsonConstructor`:

```cs
class Data
{
    [JsonConstructor()]
    public Data(IReadOnlyCollection<int> ints)
    {
        Ints = ints; // or create the copy.
    }

    public Data(IEnumerable<int> ints)
    {
        Ints = ints.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Ints { get; }
}
```

Or using property with private setter and parameterless ctor:

```cs
class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        Ints = new int[] { };
    }

    public Data(IEnumerable<int> ints)
    {
        Ints = ints.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    [JsonInclude]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Ints { get; private set; }
}
```

Other than that you can look into creating a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0).

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response but I don't think this is the solution to the issue I'm having. I don't want to create another constructor for deserialization. I want it to use this particular constructor taking IEnumerable<int>. I've read the linked article before but it does not answer my question either.

Comment: @QmlnR2F5 In short - you can't. The doc is quite explicit about that - _"The parameter names of a parameterized constructor **must match** the property names **and types**"_ Another solution is to create a custom converter.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense although it's weird to me that STJ doesn't support, to what seems to me like a very basic case. Would you happen to know if the .NET team has a planned fix for that somewhere in their backlog?

Comment: @QmlnR2F5 - nothing planned.  See [`[JsonSerializer]` Relax restrictions on ctor param type to immutable property type matching where reasonable #44428](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44428) which is currently scheduled for "Future".

Answer (score 0):

why just don't use this

```
    string data = "{\"Ints\": [24, 43, 54, 23]}";
    
    var parsed = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(data)!;

   var ints = new Data { Ints = new List<int> { 24, 43, 54, 23 } };

public class Data
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Ints { get; init; }
}
```

but if you really want to deserialize json as  a ReadOnlyCollection, you need to add a field to keep this data as ReadOnlyCollection

```
    var ints = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(data);

    var ints = new Data(new int[] { 24, 43, 54, 23 });

public class Data
{
    private  ReadOnlyCollection<int> _emptyCollection;

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Ints
    {
        get { return _emptyCollection; }
        init { _emptyCollection = value.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
    }
    
  public Data(IEnumerable<int> ints)
  {
        _emptyCollection = ints.ToList().AsReadOnly();
  }

  public Data()
  {
    _emptyCollection  = new Collection<int>().ToList().AsReadOnly();
  }
}
```

Comment: Deserialization is not the only way this class can get instantiated. It's important that the data inside it is immutable even if the original IEnumerable<T> passed to the constructor changes outside of the class. I mentioned Newtonsoft in my question.